# How to query a DOMNode using XPath in PHP?

Tags: php, xpath, bing

I'm trying to get the bing search results with XPath. Here is my code:

```
$html = file_get_contents("http://www.bing.com/search?q=bacon&first=11");
$doc = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$doc->loadHtml($html);
$x = new DOMXpath($doc);
$output = array();
// just grab the urls for now
foreach ($x->query("//li[@class='b_algo']") as $node)
{
    //$output[] = $node->getAttribute("href");
    $tmpDom = new DOMDocument();
    $tmpDom->loadHTML($node);
    $tmpDP = new DOMXPath($tmpDom);
    echo $tmpDP->query("//div[@class='b_title']//h2//a//href");
}
return $output;
```

This foreach iterates over all results, all I want to do is to extract the link and text from `$node` in `foreach`, but because `$node` itself is an object I can't create a `DOMDocument` from it. How can I query it?

Comment: Why not `//li[@class='b_algo']//div[@class='b_title']//h2//a//href` ?

Comment: Try @splash58 mentioned above. Must work.

Comment: You're not using XQuery here, PHP is not even supporting it. Please do not spam irrelevant tags.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your XPath expression tries to match non-existant `href` subelements, query `@href` for the attribute.

You don't need to create any new `DOMDocument`s, just pass the `$node` as context item:

```
foreach ($x->query("//li[@class='b_algo']") as $node)
{
    var_dump( $x->query("./div[@class='b_title']//h2//a//@href", $node)->item(0) );       
}
```

If you're just interested in the URLs, you could also query them directly:

```
foreach ($x->query("//li[@class='b_algo']/div[@class='b_title']/h2/a/@href") as $node)    
{
  var_dump($node);
}
```